# How to disable autoscaling for primary workers and enable only for secondary workers in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am spinning up a Dataproc cluster via Terraform (HCL). There I need to disable Auto-Scaling for primary workers and keep the Auto-Scaling on for only secondary workers.

Could someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable autoscaling for primary worker, you need to set the same value to the min and max number of primary instances in the autoscaling policy. For example:

```
workerConfig:
  minInstances: 10
  maxInstances: 10
secondaryWorkerConfig:
  maxInstances: 50
basicAlgorithm:
  cooldownPeriod: 4m
  yarnConfig:
    scaleUpFactor: 0.05
    scaleDownFactor: 1.0
    gracefulDecommissionTimeout: 1h
```

See more details in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#create_an_autoscaling_policy).

You can check the Terraform doc for the syntax.

Comment: Hi Dagang, thanks for looking into my question. When we give same value for min and max nodes in auto-scaling, it is erroring out.

Comment: Is the error from Terraform? Can you share the error message?

Comment: It worked actually. Thanks for help. The condition is that if we enable autoscaling in Dataproc cluster, we need to at least have one group machines with varying numbers in min and max specification.